# how to create dynamic array in mips

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

so I write the code below that create array and I want to create a dynamic array and put the row 3 element in it, any one can help

this the whole question : I've problems only in 6

Use MARS software to develop a well-documented MIPS Assembly program that:

1. defines in the data segment a static matrix named mymat consisting of 6x8 elements and
   initializes them with any float values;
2. prints the elements of array mymat 8 values per line separated by two colons :: ;
3. prompts the user to enter from the KBD 2 integer numbers col1 and col2 in the range 0 to 7 representing column numbers in the matrix mymat, validates the entered values and if wrong values are entered prints a proper error message and prompts the user to enter again.
4. swaps the elements of columns specified by the values of col1 and col2.
5. prints the elements of array mymat 8 values per line separated by two colons $$ ;
6. creates a dynamic array named new and fills it with elements from row #3 of mymat.
7. prints the elements of array new separated by one star * at the beginning of a new line.

```
.data

    #array defined 

    mymat: .float   1.1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

        .float  9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16

        .float  17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24

        .float  25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32

        .float  33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40

        .float  41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48

    LineOfColons:.asciiz "::::::::::::::::::"

    LineOfDollars:.asciiz "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"

    newline:.asciiz "\n"    

    newline_space: .asciiz "\n "

    newline_tab: .asciiz "\n \t"

    newline_hastag: .asciiz "\n#"

    comma: .asciiz "::"


.text 

.globl main

main:

#$t0 like i 

li $t0, 1

#$t1 =index of array 

li $t1,0

#how many element has printed 

li $t2,1

li $t4,8

 addi $s0,$zero,9

 sw $s0,mymat($t1)

#######################

while:



    #while loop (if $t0>48) go to exit 

    bgt $t0,48,next


    #to load the element at array mymat in  position $t1

    la $a0,mymat($t1)

    #print the element 

    li $v0, 2           

    l.s $f12,($a0)         

    syscall

    ###

        div $t2,$t4

        mfhi $t3

    

    #print ,

    la $a0,comma

    li $v0,4

      syscall  

      

    #index=indrx+4 to move to next 4 byte

    add $t1,$t1,4

    #i++  loop

    add $t0,$t0,1

    ##how many element has printed +1

    add $t2,$t2,1

    #while loop to print a line if  $t2%8 true print line

    beq $t3,0,PrintNewline

    

    j while



PrintNewline:

la $a0,newline

  li $v0,4

  syscall 

  j while

#########################
next:


######## execute the code ############



 li $v0,10 

  syscall
```

Comment: MARS has a system call to allocate memory.  Use it to get a pointer to a block of memory.   https://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html

Answer (score 0):

To create a dynamic array, you need a few things:

- A size (number of elements, then converted to number of bytes)
- A location (global, heap, stack)

And a method to obtain a pointer/reference to the start of the memory for the dynamic array

The location could be:

- Within a larger block of otherwise unused memory
  For example, put a label as last item in your `.data` section, and use that label to get the address of memory that is past the end of your global data; (this memory is available to be used if you are not also doing heap allocation).
- Heap allocated
  To allocate memory from the heap, use syscall #9 — it returns to you the pointer to the beginning of the allocated block.  (MARS & QtSpim do not support releasing the memory, but one could write a more complex malloc/free on top of the syscall that is provided.)
- Stack allocated
  To allocate memory from the stack, decrement the stack pointer — the new value of the stack pointer is the address of the beginning of your new block.  Stack memory is not appropriate if you want the memory to survive some function returning — when a function returns it should do so leaving the stack as it was upon entry.

Each of these approaches gives you the address of the block of memory for a dynamic array.  If you wanted more than one dynamic array, all these approaches will work, though for the first approach, you'll have to keep track of where the free memory is yourself (dynamically), whereas with the other approaches they will sort of help do that themselves.